# javascript:void(0) and target="_blank" behaviour

Tags: javascript, html

First of all, I am not having a real problem. I'm asking this out of curiosity only.

I accidentally run into a strange behaviour when using `javascript:void(0)` and `target="_blank"` within the same link, like this.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" target="_blank" /> Link </a>
```

I found that `Chrome` is handling this normally and not doing anything when you click the link, while `IE` and `Firefox` open up a blank new tab.

My question is, isn't `javascript:void(0)` supposed to prevent any click event firing from a link, even if it targets new tab/window? And why is `target="_blank"` overiding it?

Also what is the best approach if I am, let's say, filling the `href` attribute with some backend language and I prefer `target="_blank"` hard coded beside the `href` attribute?

Comment: I thought `javascript:void(0);` was considered bad practice.

Comment: A better approach would be to not use empty anchor tags, instead use styled spans.

Comment: How did my reply not provide an answer? The code I provided does what I believe you want - it looks like a link, but doesn't visit anything. You asked for the best approach, I gave my best approach.

Answer (score 3):

```
<a href=# onclick="return false;">I look like a link!</a>
```

Always used this.

EDIT: To your question about void(0), the onclick is supposed to have a higher priority than the href attribute because it provides richer functionality and has the capability of actually preventing the href from operating - thus my `return false`. The href is only there for robots and old browsers if the onclick event is present.

Also, whether a regular navigation is performed with oddly-formed URLs is at the discretion of the browser. If the link starts with a hash, it should just jump to a bookmark. But when it's empty or contains other protocols, it all depends on the browser if it decides to try and visit the new document. Entering the `javascript:` pseudo protocol is traditionally used for bookmarklets which are expected to work with the current page, so anything `javascript:` that doesn't do `document.write()` or other destructive modification *should* leave the page unreloaded.

EDIT2: I'm not sure what you mean by backend language in href, but consider HTML-valid `data-` attributes to give your code something to work with if it doesn't belong logically in a href attribute.

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is only code. Would you mind expanding it by adding some text to explain how it solves the problem?

Comment: The answer helped me, it may not provide an answer to the questiion, but when we type "javasxcript:void(0) open new page" in google, this page help ! thanks you

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this by using simple trick. It might be useful.

I have removed the target attribute dynamically based on the link. i.e if the link is undefined or empty or javascript:void(0), then we will remove the target attribute by using below code.

If the link is proper one, we will add the target attribute for that hyper link("second if condition" will do that, because in my page links are dynamic).

I have copied the sample html file(Test.html). 
if we want to remove the attribute on onload of the page, copy the script code in this file and paste it at the end of your required file.

If we want to apply this for dynamic links, we have to put this code in one function and we can call it when it is required.

This code will be applicable to all the hyper links in that page. We can limit this to particular set of links by using class or any other attributes.

```
Test.html
---------

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" target="_blank">Link1</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" target="_blank">Link2</a>
<a href="www.url1.com" target="_blank">Link3</a>
<a href="www.url2.com" target="_blank">Link4</a>

<script>
$("a").each(function() {

if(typeof(this.href) == 'undefined' || this.href == 'javascript:void(0);') {
    $(this).attr('href', 'javascript:void(0);');
    $(this).removeAttr('target');
}
if(typeof(this.href) != 'undefined' && this.href != 'javascript:void(0);') {
    var s_link = this.href;
    if (s_link.indexOf('http://') === -1 && s_link.indexOf('https://') === -1) {
        s_link = 'https://' + s_link;
    }   
    $(this).attr('href', s_link);
    $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
}

});
</script>
```